# Getting stream error: stream ID 1; PROTOCOL_ERROR when using Google Search API in Golang in a Container

Tags: docker, go, google-api, google-custom-search

When using a Go program inside of a docker swarm service I get a 400 status and an error message `stream ID 1; PROTOCOL_ERROR` when I call a `client.Get(url)` ) I get a 200 and the results when I `go run *.go`. I use a "Bundle of CA Root Certificates" inside of the container from Mozilla. Any Help Appreciated. My code is below.

```
client := &http.Client{Timeout: 30 * time.Second, Transport: &http.Transport{
        DisableCompression: true,
        DisableKeepAlives:  true,
    }}

    r, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(url, err) // The Google Search url and err: stream error: stream ID 1; PROTOCOL_ERROR

        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(r.StatusCode, string(bodyBytes))

    return json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(target)
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch

ADD ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

ENV MODE=production

ADD main /
CMD ["/main"]
```

Edit:
Output from Debug

```
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Transport creating client conn 0xc42030b340 to 172.217.2.234:443
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Framer 0xc4204862a0: wrote SETTINGS len=18, settings: ENABLE_PUSH=0, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=4194304, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=10485760
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Framer 0xc4204862a0: wrote WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=1073741824
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Transport encoding header ":authority" = "www.googleapis.com"
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Transport encoding header ":method" = "GET"
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Transport encoding header ":path" = "/customsearch/v1?key=hidingmykey&cx=hidingmycx&q=liquid+nitrogen&num=10&start=1"
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Transport encoding header ":scheme" = "https"
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Transport encoding header "user-agent" = "Go-http-client/2.0"
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Framer 0xc4204862a0: wrote HEADERS flags=END_STREAM|END_HEADERS stream=1 len=140
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Framer 0xc4204862a0: read SETTINGS len=18, settings: MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=100, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=1048576, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=16384
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Transport received SETTINGS len=18, settings: MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=100, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=1048576, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=16384
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Framer 0xc4204862a0: wrote SETTINGS flags=ACK len=0
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Framer 0xc4204862a0: read WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=983041
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Transport received WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=983041
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Framer 0xc4204862a0: read SETTINGS flags=ACK len=0
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Transport received SETTINGS flags=ACK len=0
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Framer 0xc4204862a0: read HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=1 len=72
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":status" = "400"
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: decoded hpack field header field "content-type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: decoded hpack field header field "referrer-policy" = "no-referrer"
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: decoded hpack field header field "content-length" = "1555"
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: decoded hpack field header field "date" = "Tue, 19 Dec 2017 12:50:17 GMT"
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Transport received HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=1 len=72
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Framer 0xc4204862a0: read RST_STREAM stream=1 len=4 ErrCode=PROTOCOL_ERROR
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Transport received RST_STREAM stream=1 len=4 ErrCode=PROTOCOL_ERROR
mycontainer.1.jdl70gy26uds@moby    | 2017/12/19 12:50:16 http2: Framer 0xc4204862a0: wrote RST_STREAM stream=1 len=4 ErrCode=CANCEL
```

Comment: To get more information to work with you can enable debug printouts for Go's http library, set the env variable `GODEBUG=http2debug=2`. With the scratch image it should work to do: `docker run --env="GODEBUG=http2debug=2" my-image`

Comment: @johlo Cool never know you could do that  Added Output to edit

Comment: I'm nit sure if this is a Docker issue or a Go issue

Comment: have you mounted /etc/ssl/certs from the host? (like docker -v /etc/ssl/certs) ? does it have a client cert in there ? i would expect that you need the ca cert to verify the other endpoint and then the client cert for your session.

Comment: Most likely there's some certificate problem, you should try @ramrunner's suggestion and try to mount/copy the hosts certificates in the container.